# Oauthcallback error with twitter

Tags: django

Oauthcallback error with twitter

using "flashingpumpkin / django-socialregistration"

After clicking Sign-in from Twitter and redirected back to mysite (127.0.0.1)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/twitter/callback/?oauth_token=w6rNt0lVPrWKgpOZkCGO1lUdRSJC8XYXxA5mGiA6k&oauth_verifier=0gkTvZhqEkGr33JZwNpwYcWtNZKJSnJDtZ2fN03Hgw

Getting this error oauthcallback.html -

> This is the error template which is shown when a user logs in via
>   OAuth and something goes wrong. No request token saved for
>   "api.twitter.com".

Any idea where to look next??

Answer (score 0):

It is answered in here: https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration/issues/101